# Can you search for a particular word within an element on a webpage? Chrome extension, Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm building a chrome extension that needs to detect whether an email contains an attachment (on gmail). I'm trying to do this by looking at the 'aria-label', which always contains the word attachment, but the rest of the text varies according to the name of the attachment. Therefore, is it possible to look to see if the word 'attachment' is contained within?

The code I've got below doesn't seem to do the trick, does str.includes not work in this context?:

```
var exists2 = document.querySelector('[aria-label=str.includes("attachment")');
```

Comment: Not sure of chrome extenstion, but in normally, `str` wont have the value of aria-label unless assigned and we cant have javascript inside html. You could perhaps just query for elements with aria-label attribute and then running `array.filter`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `var listOFAttachments = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label*="Attachment"]')`

This would return a list of all matched Nodes in the document. Note the `aria-label*` to have `includes` kind of syntax in css.

Comment: @Mate Glad this helped :). Also, don't forget to accept it as answer.